# vanilla JS/AJAX call loading gif/output sometimes delayed

Tags: javascript, ajax

Okay i am using AJAX to recive JSON data which contains information about what should happend next... basically i use a css class hide/show which i add/remove from the images/wrapper and the loading .png image

But  even tho i add/remove show/hide om the image, then add a new image src and then add add/remove css classes on the new image.

Even tho i do it in this order sometimes when the hide/show classes are added it is still the old picture for a split second before it changes to the next image src

I have tried to put a 150 milli sec delay on the end but it still

```
function newImage(voteValue, imgValue, checked) {
    if (checked == "") {
        var innerVotingWrapper = document.getElementById('innerVotingWrapper');
        innerVotingWrapper.innerHTML = "Du skal vælge en kategori";
        console.log(checked);
    } else {
        var loadingWrapper = document.getElementById('loadingWrapper');
        var imgSrc = document.getElementById('imgSrc');
        var globalRating = document.getElementById('globalRating');

        globalRating.classList.add("hide");
        globalRating.classList.remove("show");
        imgSrc.classList.add("hide");
        imgSrc.classList.remove("show");
        loadingWrapper.classList.add("show");
        loadingWrapper.classList.remove("hide");

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "pages/newImage.php";
        var params = "voteValue=" + voteValue + "&imgValue=" + imgValue + "&checked=" + checked;
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                setTimeout(func, 1000);

                function func() {
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                    console.log(jsonData.checked);
                    loadingWrapper.classList.add("hide");
                    loadingWrapper.classList.remove("show");

                    if (jsonData.imgSrc) {
                        imgSrc.src = jsonData.imgSrc;

                    }
                    if (jsonData.id) {
                        var imgValue = document.getElementById('imgValue');
                        imgValue.value = jsonData.id;
                    }
                    if (jsonData.empty) {
                        console.log('Ikke flere billeder');
                        var innerVotingWrapper = document.getElementById('innerVotingWrapper');
                        innerVotingWrapper.innerHTML = "Du har votet alle billeder kom tilbage om 24timer";
                    }


                    function showImg() {
                        globalRating.classList.add("show");
                        globalRating.classList.remove("hide");
                        imgSrc.classList.add("show");
                        imgSrc.classList.remove("hide");
                    }
                    setTimeout(showImg, 150);
                }
            }
        };
        http.send(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In think the good solution it's to regenerate an img html tag.

By changing the img src do not force the navigator to upgrade it.

To generate an img tag do :

`var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = jsonData.imgSrc;`

then you need to remove imgSrc and add the newImg.

`var parent = imgSrc.parentNode;
parent.appendChild(newImg);
parent.removeChild(srcImg);`

Comment: Thanks i will do this insted :)